# Android: Not able to open dialog in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I have a button in a fragment, when i click i need to open a dialog with listview items populated in it, but i am unable to open the dialog with the list item

```
 final ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {        

                   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
                   dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

                   ArrayAdapter<String> selectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view,R.id.text, event);
                   selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);                  
                   lv.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
                   dialog.show();                
                }        
            });
```

My listview

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where do you call `dialog.show()`?

Comment: is logcat showing any error?

Comment: @Raghunanadan  sorry it has the dialog.show().. i mean to say the the listitems are not appearing in dailog

Comment: @teekib you need to show us some more relevant info. do you have a listview inside the dialog. is the listview intialized?

Comment: @Raghunandan..yeah i have listview and i initialized it..but getting nullpointerexception

Comment: @teekib show us the stack trace

Comment: @Raghunandan   08-13 12:22:07.281: E/AndroidRuntime(13696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 12:22:07.281: E/AndroidRuntime(13696): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 12:22:07.281: E/AndroidRuntime(13696):  at com.me.myapp.FirstFragment$2.onClick(FirstFragment.java:99)
08-13 12:22:07.281: E/AndroidRuntime(13696):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
08-13 12:22:07.281: E/AndroidRuntime(13696):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
08-13 12:22:07.281: E/AndroidRuntime(13696):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

Comment: Is `event` a `List<String>` or a `String[]` instantiated and filled with data?

Comment: @Raghunandan  (FirstFragment.java:99) is   lv.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);

Comment: Your initialization of listview is wrong. intialize like this inside button click  `ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mylist)`. Dialog layout has the listview if i am not wrong so use the dialog object to initialize the listview

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué yes its ArrayList<String> event; and data is comming.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a proposal.

Comment: @teekib you are welcome and hope it helps you

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you how do i customize the dialog.?

Comment: @teekib that a different question pls post a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize ListView like this.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {        
                   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
                   dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
                   ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mylist); 
                   ArrayAdapter<String> selectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, event);
                   selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);                  
                   lv.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
                   dialog.show();                
                }        
            });
```

Edit: You have a custom dialog. You have a layout `list_view` with a textview and a listview. So to initialize listview you should use the dialog object to initialize the listview

Similarly to initialize the textview

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `dialog.show()` to make it appear on screen!

**EDIT:**

Ok, the problem is that you find the listview **before** the dialog is created. Thus, `lv` is not a valid reference to any object.

Move the `findViewById` before setting the content view:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {        

               Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
               dialog.setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
               ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
               dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

               ArrayAdapter<String> selectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view,R.id.text, event);
               selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);                  
               lv.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);
               dialog.show();                
            }        
        });
```

Comment: dialog layout is `list_view`. the one used in adapter is also the same `ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view,R.id.text, event);`